# Native WinRT Component Extension SDK for Windows Phone 8 apps

Tags: c#, c++, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime

I want to create a native [WinRT Extension SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127117.aspx) that I could use from both C# and C++ **Windows Phone 8** projects.

How exactly am I supposed to structure this Extension SDK?

I try to do it like I do for Windows Store apps:

```
    SDKName\
        SDKVersion\
            Redist\
                    Debug\
                            ARM\ (Debug DLLs for ARM)
                            X86\ (Debug DLLs for X86)
                    Release\
                            ARM\ (Release DLLs for ARM)
                            X86\ (Release DLLs for X86)
            References\
                    CommonConfiguration\
                            Neutral\ (winmd file)
```

And I place it under “C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\ExtensionSDKs”.

But when I hit F5, it doesn’t copy the DLL files into the App output folder, it copies the winmd file.  It should be the other way around.  Even when I put both winmd and DLL under the Reference folder, it throws an exception at runtime with “class not registered”.

How do I fix this?

Comment: This seems to be a similar problem http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36562267-dc90-44fa-9413-391f9d2e3801/extension-sdk-for-windows-phone-using-winrt-component?forum=wpdevelop